# How to know when to clone in java?

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I am having a problem understanding the clone method in Java.

In this example the output is 1.

```
int[][]x = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int[][]y = new int[2][];
y[0] = x[0].clone();
y[1] = x[1].clone();
x[0][0] = 0;
System.out.println(y[0][0]);
```

In this example the output is 100   8

```
 int[][][] x = {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}};
 int[][][] y = new int[2][2][];
 y[0] = x[0].clone();
 y[1][1] = x[1][1].clone();
 x[0][0][0] = 100;
 x[1][1][1] = 200;
 System.out.println(y[0][0][0]+" "+y[1][1][1]);
```

Why does the value for the y array change in the second example but not the first?

Comment: I get 100 8, I expect it to be 1 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

To understand this, you must understand (1) what a multidimensional array is in Java, and (2) that `clone()` is "shallow".

I'm going to start use 2D arrays in these examples, because they are a little simpler.

(1) A 2D array in Java is an array of arrays.

```
int[][] a = new int[4][];
a[0] = new int[1];
a[1] = new int[8];
a[3] = new int[0];
```

This is an array of four arrays of `ints`: an array of 1 `int`, an array of 8 `int`s,  `null`, and an array of no `int`s.

(2) Now, `clone()` does a *shallow* copy. That means that it creates a copy of the array (or object) with the same elements, but the elements of that copied array (or object) are the same as the original.

That means that if I have

```
int[][] b = a.clone();
```

then `b` is a different array than `a`, with the same elements. If I do `a[0] = new int[45]`, then `b` is unaffected.

Remember, however, that the *elements* of `b` are the same as the elements of `a`. So if I do

```
a[0][0] = 1
```

that affects `b[0]`, since `a[0]` and `b[0]` are the same array in memory.

---

Now, what about your case?

```
int[][]x = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int[][]y = new int[2][];
y[0] = x[0].clone();
y[1] = x[1].clone();
```

You essential do a "2-deep" clone on a 2D array. That is, `x` and `y` are different. And `x[0]` and `y[0]` are different. But `x[0][0]` and `y[0][0]` are the same in memory. But, oh, it looks like that is just an `int`, and you can't mutate an `int`, like you could an array.

In the second example, you do essentially do a 2-deep clone on a 3D array. You can (and do) mutate `x[0][0]`, which is the same as `y[0][0]`.

Comment: Ok. So in my first example, how come when x[0][0] = 0; it doesn't have any effect on y[0]?

Comment: Actually, in general, what you need to understand is the difference between deep and shallow copies. In other words... _pointers_ .

Comment: @PaulDraper Thank you. I think I understand it a little better. The most confusing part for me is understanding why y[0]=x.clone() does not point to the x array in the first example while it does in the second example.